# What is a Domain Model

Tags: design-patterns, dns

I have read the wikipedia definition of a domain model. I still don't get it. I have been reading alot of posts for NHibernate and almost in every post I read I see the term Domain Model. What exactly is it and does any one have an example of a domain model.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A domain model is a visual representation of real situation objects in a domain.
A domain is an area of concern. Its used to refer to the area you are dealing with.
The model is a diagram, for domain models the class diagram UML is mostly used. The class diagram is only used for the notation.
**The term domain model does not mean a set of diagrams describing software classes.**

So for example imagine a store. For that store you want to build a brand new Point Of Sale system (lets call it POS system). A POS system is a computerized application used to record sale and handle payments. So you focus on the domain of the POS system.
Now you will conceptualize the objects that will be used for this system.
So you will get objects like: Sale, Payment, Register, Item etc.
In a domain model you model these objects and draw associations between them so that you have an high level idea how this system will work.
An example of the POS domain model will be like this:

[image]

Comment: You nailed it. Domain is actually the problem that we are solving, and modelling is the abstract representation of higher level objects and its association with each other.

Answer (score 54):

Basically, it's the "model" of the objects required for your business purposes.

Say you were making a sales tracking website - you'd potentially have classes such as Customer, Vendor, Transaction, etc.  That entire set of classes, as well as the relationships between them, would consititute your [Domain Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model).

Comment: Thank you for not using the phrase in the definition. The "domain is the problem domain." Totally unhelpful. Your answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 27):

If you were to take your program and strip away the gui and the DBMS, and replace it with a command line interface, and a MySQL server instance, then port the whole thing to a different platform with different system calls and file system access api calls, the part that you didn't change in that process is the domain model.

Answer (score 3):

This article might help:

https://dddcommunity.org/learning-ddd/what_is_ddd/

The basic idea is that the Domain is the problem domain and the model is... well the model of it. The above article is puts it far more eloquently than I would and there are plenty of other resources there if you want to go down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1):

Answering from perspective of Eric Evans's *"Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software"* book:

> [A **domain] model** is a system of abstractions that describes selected aspects of a domain and can be used to solve problems related to that domain.

Practically it means the following. On the input we have domain experts, domain knowledge sources and requirement for a software product. **Modeling** would mean eliciting the relevant [for the software under the development] part of that domain knowledge and representing it somehow. If I understood the author correctly, the model can be represented in many ways: as a text, as diagrams, as a code, in form of oral communication. The model is updated in parallel with iterative software development, being reworked for the need of the software development.

So a **domain model** is a selective and structured representation of domain knowledge relevant for a given software development project.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you for elucidating this point. I was just about to put a question here about What is domain model as per DDD ? But you just answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Domain model is a collection of constructs that accurately models one particular business domain. Simply put, it’s a collection of entities, enumerations, value objects, exceptions/custom exceptions, interfaces, services, etc. All of that represents the domain model. Anything that has any impact in describing the business domain. On the other hand, any construct that doesn’t take part in this description; the UI code, infrastructure related code, persistence objects, various tools, etc; are considered as third-party/outer concerns in the context of DDD.

Check out this short article

https://fiseni.com/posts/what-is-a-domain-model/

Answer (score 1):

in a super simple sentence I can say:

> Domain model is an abstraction of domain, expressed as code
> implementation which is a view not reality of business use case.